# Finding outliers in a scatter plot / pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math, scatter-plot, quantile

I am creating an interactive scatter plot which has thousands of data points, and I would like to dynamically find the outliers, in order to annotate only those points which are not too bunched together.

I am doing this currently in a slightly hackey way by using the following query, where users can provide values for q_x, q_y and q_xy (say 0.998, 0.994 and 0.95):

```
outliers = df[(df['x'] > df['x'].quantile(q_x)) | (df['y'] > df['y'].quantile(q_y))
          | ((df['x'] > df['x'].quantile(q_xy)) & (df['y'] > df['y'].quantile(q_xy)))]
```

This kind of achieves what I want, but the user has to modify three variables to get their desired selection, and even then it's a bit uneven, as the three parts of the query focus on seperate sections of the data.

Is there a better, more mathematically sound way to find outliers for a set of x, y points?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide code to set up a reproducible example? It's difficult to judge a method without having example(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [extremely useful article](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-variate-outlier-detection-in-python-e900a338da10) which answered this for me.

The code I've used:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

outliers = 50 # or however many you want
l = len(df.index)
isf = IsolationForest(
    n_estimators=100,
    random_state=42,
    contamination=0.5 if outliers / l > 0.5 else outliers / l
)
preds = isf.fit_predict(df[['x', 'y']].to_numpy())
df["iso_forest_outliers"] = preds
```

Where `outliers` is the number of outliers I want to limit the result to. Outliers are listed as -1 in the column `'iso_forest_outliers'`. The value of `contamination` must be between 0 and 0.5, which is why there is the if else statement.

Comment: How do you define the number of outliers that you want?

Comment: I've edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function which takes a dict of rules:

```
def is_outlier(df, rules):
    m_or = pd.Series(False, index=df.index)
    for cols, q in rules.items():
        cols = [cols] if isinstance(cols, str) else cols
        m_and = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
        for col in cols:
            m_and &= df[col] > df[col].quantile(q)
        m_or |= m_and
    return m_or.rename('outliers')
```

Usage:

```
np.random.seed(142)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (20, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
m = is_outlier(df, {'x': 0.998, 'y': 0.994, ('x', 'y'): 0.95})
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, m], axis=1)
     x   y  outliers
0   21   5     False
1   27  12     False
2   26  45     False
3   16  49      True
4   13  34     False
5   12  11     False
6   23  31     False
7   30  21     False
8   11   2     False
9   20  19     False
10  18  36     False
11   9  23     False
12   8  23     False
13  22  15     False
14   1  33     False
15   2  24     False
16  24  36     False
17  40  17      True
18  36  29     False
19  37  32     False
```